# Find matching indices for pattern vector in grep

Tags: r

Is there an easy way to find corresponding vector indices when working with `grep`?

```
v=c(123,456,789,651)
pat=c(1,35,47,8)
id=grep(paste0(pat, collapse="|"), v)
v[id]

[1] 123 789 651
```

I would like to generate:

```
pat_id
[1] 1 4 1
```

So that `pat[pat_id]` would give me the values in `pat` that matched.

```
pat[pat_id]
[1] 1 8 1
```

`match()` cannot be used in this case because strings have to be identical to count as a match.

Comment: your `id` already has what you want (`pat_id`) right? If you do `pat[id]` you would get `[1] 1 8` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I just edited my question to more accurately reflect the problem. `pat_id` is not necessarily the same as `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over `v` and use `str_detect` since it is vectorised  to find if the pattern exists in any of them and return the index or the vector directly.

```
library(stringr)
unlist(sapply(v, function(x) which(str_detect(x, as.character(pat)))))
#[1] 1 4 1
```

If the final goal is to get `pat` vectors instead we can directly do

```
unlist(sapply(v, function(x) pat[str_detect(x, as.character(pat))]))
#[1] 1 8 1
```

Comment: This doesn't work if `v` contains a repeated matching patten. See edited question.